# SQL How do I extract time from a date to HH:MI:SS PM/AM?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to change a format of the dates to format HH:MI:SS PM/AM in SQL Oracle.

I want to use it in case when like this:

case when to_char(a.dtime,'HH:MI:SS') >= 12:00:00 then to_char(a.dtime,'HH:MI:SS PM') else null end as date

but SQL does not want to show me all to_char times > 12:00 but it shows only those where there is 12:%%:%%.

And it does not work with to_date.
Any suggestions? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`TO_CHAR( datetime, format )`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm) to format a `DATE` column. The format options are given [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924).

This would give you the time part of a date value (12-hour clock plus AM/PM):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( column_name,'HH:MI:SS AM') 
FROM   your_table
```

**Edit - Addressing the update**

You can do:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN TO_NUMBER( TO_CHAR( a.dtime_appl_creation, 'HH24' ) ) >= 12
            THEN TO_CHAR( a.dtime, 'HH:MI:SS PM' )
            END AS "date"
FROM   table_name
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT to_char(sysdate,'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mi:ss am') 
FROM dual
```

Answer (score 1):

```
case 
  when a.dtime_appl_creation-trunc(a.dtime_appl_creation) > 0.5 then 'after noon'
  else 'before noon' 
end
```